# Spring JMX - map entries to attribute name and value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jmx

Spring Boot exposes sone endpoints as JMX Beans, and some of their getData method return a map. Is there a way to take the entries and expose them as attribute name and attribute value, instead of a single value?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement `DynamicMBean`.

This interface allows you to define dynamic attributes, methods, notifications and more to the JMX server. I used it once to make one of my class be able to implement two or more MXBean interfaces. pretty neat.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/DynamicMBean.html